# sed string replacement for ... does not work

Tags: text, sed, replace

I am trying the following:

```
sed -i 's/.../string/g' log_file
```

However it removes some characters in every line as well as adds 'string' at the beginning of every line.

How can I go about ONLY replacing the match for '...'

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to replace dots? Escape them. `sed -i 's/\.\.\./string/g' log_file`

Comment: Aha, I tried to escape, but I only escaped the first one thinking that would do it!